# Copy the tiff images based on date range using Python

Tags: python, shutil

I am writing a python script to copy the tiff images based on selected date range i.e, 02-03-2018: 03-04-2019 so on, my input data name format is Mask_ndvi_NDVI_20160424.tif, Mask_ndvi_NDVI_20160504 so on. i have a code but it needs to change, any help would be appreciated

```
import shutil
import os

source = r'D:\Corrected'
dest1 = r'D:\2018'
dest2 = r'D:\2019'
dest2 = r'D:\2020'
dest2 = r'D:\2021'


files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if (f.startswith[20-04-2017:20-04-2018]:
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
    elif (f.startswith[20-04-2018:20-04-2019]
        shutil.move(f, dest2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files don't have dates in that format, why would you look for them?  If the date is not at the beginning, why would you use `.startswith`?  And what's significant about April 20 here?

Do you want these sorted into directories by year?  That's easy:

```
import shutil
import os

source = r'D:\Corrected'
dest1 = r'D:\2018'
dest2 = r'D:\2019'
dest2 = r'D:\2020'
dest2 = r'D:\2021'
#0123456789.123456789.123456
#Mask_ndvi_NDVI_20160424.tif

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    year = f[15:19]
    shutil.move( f, f"D:/{year}" )
```

If you actually want a ranges like that:

```
for f in files:
    xdate = f[15:23]
    if '20170420' <= xdate < '20180420':
        shutil.move( f, dest1 )
    elif '20180420' <= xdate < '20190420':
        shutil.move( f, dest2 )
    ...etc...
```

If you don't like the hardcoded column numbers, remove the exception and split the string on the underscores:

```
for f in files:
    xdate = f[:-4].split('_')[-1]
    ...same...
```